# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 - Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am try to build my first Flutter app but there is a problem. Here the Debug Console screen;

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\johnlocke\first_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
               > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/209.85.229.99] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 1m 48s
  Command: C:\Users\johnlocke\first_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

On the other hand, Google Chrome can not access this url; "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom"

but when I use VPN on Opera, I can access the link. So I think the problem is related to proxy.

Comment: Welcome to SO! So further what it is exposed on your error, it is difficult to help you without the code that is failing.

Comment: Hi, I just created a new flutter project. I didn't write any code.